# retain/sustain, are they interchangeable in the give sentences?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I can't **retain** my attention when I read novels.

I can't **sustain** my attention when I read novels.

I looked up both words' meanings and, in this case, both should mean the same thing, that's what I think. But, do they mean the same thing here, and are interchangeable?

Answer (score 1):

I don't find "retain" idiomatic in this context. The use of the words is consistent with imagining "attention" as something you hold up, like a flag in your hand.

"Retain" means "keep", or "keep hold of", but has no implication of keeping the object in use, or holding it up, merely continuing to possess it: it might be in a store, for example. I can imagine it being used of the thing the person is focussing their attention on: *Novels can't retain my attention*, but not of the person attending.

"Sustain" means "keep something going" or "hold something up", and fits well with the metaphor.

Answer (score 1):

The book **keeps**, **retains**, or **sustains** the reader's attention or interest.

If you're referring to an inability to stay focused when reading *any* book, and it's not the fault of the particular book, you could use the verb **maintain**:

> She could not maintain concentration when reading.